# GameObject following another GameObject smooth Java

Tags: java

So in my game i have a player, which holds a bulb in his hand.(The bulb is an own GameObject like that player) Right now I am setting the Bulb position to the Player position so that the bulb lays in the players hand. What i want to do is that, when the player moves the bulb follows the player, with a bit of delay.

```
public void tick() {
    bulbX = playerX + 20;
    bulbY = playerY - 3;
}
```

Any ideas??

Many thanks, Maxi

Comment: I was answering your question about shooting bullet toward cursor when you deleted it. It will also help here, I think, so it's not off topic. First, realize that an (x,y) coordinate basically _is_ a vector. Then, google up the following and read: "subtracting vectors" (that will provide a vector from one object to the other if you subtract their locations, this gets the "translation vector"), "how to calculate vector magnitude", "unit vector", then divide the translation vector by the magnitude to get a unit vector, multiply by your desired speed to get (x,y) velocity, multiply by tick time.

Comment: You’re the best. Thank you really much. I really appreciate your support. I figured out a way doing it. @Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it up so the bulb is always moving towards the player.

```
public void tick() {
    bulbX += (playerX - bulbX)/2;
    bulbY += (playerY - bulbY)/2;
}
```

This way, the bulb will be moving towards the player faster if it's further away. You might need to tune the 1/2 parameter.

I also like to add time differences to my code, so the game won't slow down with the framerate.

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(running){
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float timeDiff = (time2-time1)/1000f;
    time1 = time2;
    tick(timeDiff);
}
```

and the tick method:

```
public void tick(float timeDiff){
    float factor = 2;
    bulbX += (playerX - bulbX)*factor*timeDiff;
    bulbY += (playerY - bulbY)*factor*timeDiff;
}
```

This way, with a high enough framerate, the bulb will aproach the player exponentially.

Comment: @MaxiKeller see my updated answer, i think it will work even better for you

Comment: @MaxiKeller ThijsStee's answer provides an example of what my comment above is about. Bulb's position vector is (bulbX, bulbY), player's is (playerX, playerY). In first example of `tick()`, vector from bulb to player is found by subtracting the two vectors `player - bulb`. The answer uses an odd case (but reasonable given the situation) for the velocity, but in the second tick example (`tick(float)`), `factor` is essentially the `velocity * unit_vector`, then it multiplies by the time. So most of the elements are here. The part missing for your other Q is "get a unit vector, multiply by speed"